# property is undefined in component by subscribe to get method outside of ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, subscribe

i have mentioned in comments when i console log the selected property with in `ngOnInit` it does console the object, however outside of this block this when i console this property it is undefined. can some on help how to get it work.. or any other solution

```
      import { Product } from './../../Models/ProductModel';
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        // import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Rx";
        import 'rxjs';
        import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
        import { ProductService } from 'app/products/product.service';
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-product-detail',
          templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
        })
        export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {
          public selectedProduct: Product;
          private productIndex: string;
          // private subscription: Subscription;

          constructor(private router: Router,
                      private route: ActivatedRoute,
                      private PService: ProductService) { }

          ngOnInit() {

             this.route.params.subscribe(
              (params: any) => {
                this.productIndex = params['id'];

         }
            );


                this.PService.getProduct(this.productIndex).subscribe((data: any) =>{
                 // return the object
                 console.log(data.product)

               return this.selectedProduct = data.product,
                 //output the here object
                 console.log(this.selectedProduct);

        }

                );

        // output undefined 
                console.log(this.selectedProduct);


          }







this is the getProduct method in my service

    getProduct(id:string){
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/products/'+id, { headers : headers})
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch( (error: any) =>
      {

        this.ErS.getError(error.json());
        return Observable.throw(error);
      })



    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: Did you even check the duplicate question with answer? It will always be undefined outside the callback.

Comment: thanks . alot..  :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the purpose of this code is reget the data every time the routing parameter changes? If that is correct, then the getProduct call needs to be within the subscribe method.

Like this:

```
     ngOnInit() {

         this.route.params.subscribe(
          (params: any) => {
             this.productIndex = params['id'];

             this.PService.getProduct(this.productIndex).subscribe((data: any) =>{
             // return the object
             console.log(data.product)

             return this.selectedProduct = data.product,
             //output the here object
             console.log(this.selectedProduct);
            });
     });

           // output undefined 
            console.log(this.selectedProduct);
   }
```

The last console.log will display an undefined because it is executed when the component is initialized and BEFORE the product is retrieved.

Here is what is happening:

1. The component is initialized and runs ngOnInit.
2. The parameter is subscribed to.
3. The console log at the bottom attempts to display the selected
   product and there is none ... so undefined.
4. The change in parameter is processed and the code within the
   `params.subscribe()` is executed.
5. The parameter is obtained from the route and used to call
   getProduct.
6. The Observable returned from getProduct is subscribed to.
7. At some later point, the data is returned from the back-end
   server and the code within the `getProduct().subscribe()` is
   executed.
8. The two console.logs within the `getProduct().subscribe()` are
   executed and display the appropriate product.

Make sense?

Comment: actually i was doing it same as above.. got no luck

Comment: What do you mean? What is your actual question here?